# SQL query to get WooCommerce products by category is not working, what am I missing?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following SQL code that works badly because when I try to filter by product category it displays empty records:

SQL code:

```
SELECT
    wp_posts.ID,
    CONCAT( '<a href="', wp_posts.guid, '">', wp_posts.post_title, '</a>' ) AS nazwa,
    product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl.NAME AS kategoria,
    product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl.NAME AS jednostka,
    product_quant.meta_value AS ilość,
    product_price.meta_value AS cena,
    product_weight.meta_value AS waga,
    product_sku.meta_value AS sku 
FROM
    wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta product_quant ON product_quant.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
    AND product_quant.meta_key = "_stock"
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta product_price ON product_price.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
    AND product_price.meta_key = "_price"
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta product_weight ON product_weight.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
    AND product_weight.meta_key = "_weight"
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta product_sku ON product_sku.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
    AND product_sku.meta_key = "_sku"
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT NAME
        ,
        object_id AS id 
    FROM
        wp_terms AS product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl_terms
        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl_termtaxonomy ON product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_id = product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl_terms.term_id 
        AND product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl_termtaxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel_product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl ON product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = rel_product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl.term_taxonomy_id 
    ) AS product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl ON product_taxonomy_product_cat_tbl.ID = wp_posts.id
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT NAME
        ,
        object_id AS id 
    FROM
        wp_terms AS product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl_terms
        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl_termtaxonomy ON product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_id = product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl_terms.term_id 
        AND product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl_termtaxonomy.taxonomy = 'pa_j-m'
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel_product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl ON product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = rel_product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl.term_taxonomy_id 
    ) AS product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl ON product_taxonomy_pa_j_m_tbl.ID = wp_posts.id 
WHERE
    1 = 1 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
```

How to improve the code so that filtering by product category works?

The operation of the code is shown on the website https://server515851.nazwa.pl/wordpress/wpn_hutniczy/o-magazynie/

The idea is to filter by categories in the tree on the left side of the page.

Comment: Question: why are you querying the database directly instead of using the [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class?

Comment: I am a beginner I am asking for the WP_Query code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to get WooCommerce products by category using the [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class:

```
<?php
$cats_array = array(23); // Set here the ID of the selected category(ies)

$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // How many products to show per page
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cats_array
        )
    )
);

$products_by_category = new WP_Query($query_args);

// This category has published products, display them
if ( $products_by_category->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
    <ul class="product-list">
        <?php while ( $products_by_category->have_posts() ) : $products_by_category->the_post(); ?>
            <?php
            // Get product meta data.
            $stock = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock', true );
            $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true );
            $weight = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_weight', true );
            $sku = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sku', true );
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <p>Price: <?php echo $price; ?></p>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

    <div class="product-list-pagination">
        <?php 
            echo paginate_links(
                array(
                    'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                    'total'        => $products_by_category->max_num_pages,
                    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                    'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                    'show_all'     => false,
                    'type'         => 'plain',
                    'end_size'     => 2,
                    'mid_size'     => 1,
                    'prev_next'    => true,
                    'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Previous', 'text-domain' ) ),
                    'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Next', 'text-domain' ) ),
                    'add_args'     => false,
                    'add_fragment' => '',
                )
            );
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    // Reset the global $the_post
    wp_reset_query();
} // No products found
else {
    ?>
    <p>No products found under this category.</p>
    <?php
}
```

`$cats_array` is an array of product category ID(s). You need to populate this array somehow when the user selects one or more categories from the category tree on the left (via [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) maybe? [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)? You decide).

To see what the parameters in `$query_args` do please check out the [WP_Query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for more details.

Finally, the `if/else` block renders a list of products by category (if found). You may need to change to adapt it to your needs of course.

As a bonus I added extra code to paginate the results (see [paginate_links()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) for more).

If you have any particular questions about the code please feel free to ask.

Comment: and is it possible to modify or adapt this sql query to the WP_Query code?
How to do it?
Sorry for the big questions but I'm a beginner

Comment: This code already gets products by category. Only thing you need to change is the category ID(s) (as mentioned above), the HTML output, and possibly other parameters if needed.

Comment: Also just updated the code so it retrieves the product's meta data (price, sku, etc). Hopefully that helps.

Comment: thank you very much and it can be set to select all categories automatically?
thank you very much for help

Comment: To display products from all categories just delete the `tax_query` key and its array, then add it back when you need to filter by specific category IDs.

Comment: I mean using this code in such a way that there is a table like on the page https://server515851.nazwa.pl/wordpress/wpn_hutniczy/o-magazynie/

and that there is a category tree on the left and it is possible to filter products in the table according to these categories, after selecting them, you can do it.

I will buy a good beer 

thank you very much for your help and tips.

Comment: Possible? Yes. However, that's something you should figure out yourself. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, mate. We're here to help you with __your__ code, not to write it for you :P

Comment: I have this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Query' not found
I can ask for help

Comment: WP_Query is a core class so you getting that error means you're trying to use this code before WordPress has loaded? Or in a file outside WordPress?

Comment: I'm calling this code from the product.php file
can you somehow call wp_query in a separate file?

Comment: And where is this product.php file? Is it a separate file somewhere somewhere in your public_html folder? Because if product.php doesn't have access to any of the WordPress classes, functions, and APIs then that'd explain why you're getting this error. Explain in detail how your code works so I (or anyone else reading this) can help.

Comment: product.php file is located in the root of wordpress public_html

Comment: Then that's why you're getting this error. The file doesn't get access to any of the WordPress stuff like that. Any reason why you're doing it this way instead of, for example, adding your code to the theme's functions.php file or to a custom plugin?

Comment: I'm using wpdatatables and that's why I'm using the product.php file can call query.php at the beginning of the code will it help?

Comment: In that case if I were you I'd try using this instead: https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/creating-new-wpdatatables-with-table-constructor/generating-wordpress-db-queries-with-table-constructor/

Comment: Ah but then you'd need to find a way to reload the table and have it show products by category as well. It might be a good idea to contact the developer of the wpdatatables plugin and see if they can assist with that.

Comment: thank you very much